# Scene Builder window (and JavaFX app) not displaying properly

Tags: javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I recently built a JavaFX app using Eclipse on Ubuntu 14.04.  It works fine.  However when I run the app on Windows, the app window doesn't render properly (only the border and title of the window appear, and the inside is a copy of the background).  I thought that it may be the fxml so I opened the project in Windows in Eclipse and downloaded Scene Builder 8.0.0 64bit to open the fxml.  But when trying to install Scene Builder the same thing happens as with the app.  The window does not render properly, the inside is just a copy of the background, and only the title and borders are visible.  What's going on?

**UPDATE**: When I run the executable jar rather than the .exe installer,I get the following output: WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0
x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5. 
The same problem happens: the window doesn't render properly.